# ActiveMQ failoverTransport fails reconnection if on application startup queue is not reachable

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have an application that uses ActiveMQ with the help of Spring. I followed [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jms).

This is my connection string:

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=100&startupMaxReconnectAttempts=3
```

I used `failover` to activate automatic reconnection if the queue becomes unreachable. This works fine if the first connection is ok. on the logs I can see that the connection with the queue is lost and then recovered.

But if the queue is not available when the application starts then all I can see in the logs is:

```
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination MYQUEUE Cause: The JMS connection has failed: Connection refused
```

There is no further information.

In the connection url I added `startupMaxReconnectAttempts=3` in order to let the application to start, otherwise it was waiting indefinitely for the queue to be available.

Is it possible to have a configuration that can reconnect to the queue even if during startup is not available?

Please let me know if I have to mention other details.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection is being refused then it is likely that the remote broker is down and the client cannot reconnect.  In such a case there isn't much that can be done other than to keep trying or give up (or setup a primary and backup broker topology).  If the broker is up but is refusing the auto create queues due to some security policy then likewise the client will fail to reconnect as it cannot reconstruct its state from the previous failover.  These are all issues you need to address in your broker configuration and availability setup.